# How to interpolate the local maxima detected in a speech?

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition

I have a matlab code which is used to find the local maxima of a speech. I managed to plot the original speech and the local maxima in the same graph. However, I want to perform linear interpolation in order to show in the same graph the envelope of the speech by connecting the local maxima. How should I do? 
here is the code:

```
    a=wavread('F3.wav');
    peaks = localMaximum(a,[100]); 
figure; plot(a); hold on; plot(peaks,a(peaks),'ro');
```

the localMaximum is a function from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14498-local-maxima---minima

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% just some test data
a=randn(1,1000);
peaks = localMaximum(a,[100]); 

figure; plot(a); hold on; plot(peaks,a(peaks),'ro');

% values where to interpolate
x = 1:length(a);
% interpolate
v = interp1(peaks,a(peaks),x,'linear');
% visualize
plot(x,v,'g-');
```

But why interpolate. The same can be visualized by:

```
plot(peaks,a(peaks),'g-');
```

Comment: Thanks @Steffen, your answer is really highly appreciated..the idea of interpolate comes after reading an article. Actually I want to show the envelope. your code works for my situation. However, How can I display the peak as well? I add the following line, but the error showed "index exceed matrix dimension". I add this code "plot(peaks,a(peaks),'g-');hold on; plot(peaks,a(peaks,'ro'));

Comment: Ops sorry, ok @steffen..I know where the code is wrongly added...It is the bracket..however, I really want to thank you.God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

Another (simple) way to calculate envelope is by full/half-wave rectification of the input speech and passing it through a low pass filter. The cutoff frequency for the filter determines how "squiggly/smooth" you'd want the envelope to be.

This method may be computationally more efficient than peak finding and interpolating.